# How does dup work on jagged arrays?

Tags: d, jagged-arrays, dup

I would expect it to duplicate only nested arrays slices instead of the whole deep copy of array, but suddenly I've got a doubt.

Comment: it only makes a shallow copy, the nested slices are not copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ratchet freak is right, it is a shallow copy. You can see the source to the dup function in dmd2/src/druntime/src/rt/lifetime.d. The function is called _adDupT.

It is a pretty short function where the main work is a call to memcpy(). Above the function, you can see a representation of an array: struct { size_t length; void* ptr; }

A jagged array would be an array of arrays, so the memory would look like [length0, ptr0, length1, ptr1, length2, ptr2....]

Since memcpy over those pointers doesn't follow them, that means slice.dup is a shallow copy.

This is generally true with anything that copies slices, it is always shallow copies unless you do something yourself. So struct A {char[] str; } A a, b; a = b; would also shallow copy, so assert(a.str is b.str).

If you want to do a deep copy, the simplest way is to just loop over it:

```
T[][] newArray;
foreach(item; oldArray)
      newArray ~= item.dup;
```

(you can also preallocat newArray.length = oldArray.length and assign with indexes if you want to speed it up a bit)

A deep copy of a struct could be done with compile time reflection, though I prefer to write a clone method or something in there since it is a bit more clear.

I'm not aware of a phobos function with this premade.